# How to convert an array from javascript to a java array?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, json

I have this javascript code :

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'assignRenameRuleToAgency.do',
    data: {agenciesId:agenciesId,ruleId: JSON.stringify ( ruleIDd ) },
    success: function(response) {
        toastr.success(response.message);
    }
})
```

in the server side I did this :

```
String  ruleId = request.getParameter("ruleId");
String[]  agenciesId = request.getParameterValues("agenciesId");
```

`ruleId` was correct, but `agenciesId` was `null`.

Comment: Well, isn't agenciesId simply a parameter the same way as ruleId? Couldn't you just invoke `request.getParameter("agenciesId")`?

Comment: Have you tried what @wassgren has suggested?

Answer (score 0):

It is a single `String`, not an array! You can change your structure to

```
agenciesId: [agenciesId]
```

then it will be an array.

I would however map the JSON message to a single POJO, for example by using [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHome).

Comment: I tried :   data: {agenciesId: [agenciesId],ruleId: JSON.stringify ( ruleIDd ) }, but allways request.getParameterValues("agenciesId"); return null

Comment: So `agenciesId` is a JavaScript array? If so, please show us how do you perform the JSON deserialization.

Answer (score 0):

Get JSON response from ajax call and then convert that json response to Java objects using below solutions.
[Click here to know the working examples](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)

Answer (score 0):

If the parameter for `ruleId` can be received the way you describe the following should work:

```
String ruleId = request.getParameter("ruleId");
String agenciesId = request.getParameter("agenciesId");
```

Comment: agenciesId was an array in ajax, I did that too but always null

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

```
String[] myJsonData = request.getParameterValues("json[]");
```